# Cannot login offline

Tags: c#, .net, spotify, libspotify

I can login with username and password when internet is connected. If I disconnect internet when logged in I can still listen to offline lists. If I reconnect internet I get full functionality again without any actions on my part.

But when internet is unavailable when I start my application I cannot login to listen to offline tracks.

I have tried to login with blob instead of password without success (with or without internet). I have also played around with "rememberme" but that does not seem to survive a restart of my application.

I have tried empty strings ("") as well as IntPtr.Zero for password and blob when using the other.

No success. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know how spotify works, but I know you will never be able to log in to any online service without an internet connection. If offline tracks are not stored on the local computer, you won't have access to them.

Answer (score 0):

I think that @Kendall Frey hit the nail on the head, offline support is implemented in libspotify, but you probably at least need to be online to get it started. This isn't the case in Spotify's mobile and desktop clients, however they are not built on libspotify. So sorry, I don't believe that there is any way around this limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Offline login should actually work in libspotify using the credentials blob under the following conditions:

- The user has successfully logged in online at least once before.
- You are allowing libspotify to create and maintain an on-disk cache.
- libspotify is able to correctly write credentials to that cache and verify them next time.
- You are correctly allowing libspotify to clean up as your application exits.

The cache is the important part here. You must pass libspotify a location on-disk that's readable and writeable.

Also **very important** is logging out correctly. You *must* either log out the user and wait for that process to complete as your application exits or call `flush_caches()` and wait for that to complete. Otherwise, libspotify won't be able to correctly write to the cache to enable offline login next time. If you're just exiting your process without proper libspotify cleanup, offline login won't work.

Comment: I believe I'm doing all that. I do get a logout callback, and I do have a cache. I guess this means that it is worth while playing around with blob. You do not happen to know if I have to omit user and/or password, and if omitted if I should pass zero pointer or void strings?

Comment: You have to provide a username with a blob, and pass NULL to the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You were absolutely correct iKenndac!
In fact the problem was behind the keyboard, as I got confused by the connection states and the sp_error of the login callback.

**I did in fact log in successfully the same way as I did when connected. That is with username and password and "remember me".**

Confusion came from the comments in api.h

> SP_CONNECTION_STATE_LOGGED_OUT = 0, ///< User not yet logged in
>
> SP_CONNECTION_STATE_LOGGED_IN = 1, ///< Logged in against a Spotify access point
>
> SP_CONNECTION_STATE_DISCONNECTED = 2, ///< Was logged in, but has now been disconnected
>
> SP_CONNECTION_STATE_UNDEFINED = 3, ///< The connection state is undefined
>
> SP_CONNECTION_STATE_OFFLINE = 4  ///< Logged in in offline mode

When I start my app without internet connection I first get login callback saying SP_ERROR_OK and then I get SP_CONNECTION_STATE_DISCONNECTED (Was logged in, but has now been disconnected)

I expected SP_CONNECTION_STATE_OFFLINE (Logged in in offline mode) when not connected to internet.

But "now working"